# How to get Y axis label in android mpchart?

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I have plotted graph with corresponding X and Y axis.

Now how to get Y axis label and compare and place another label in Y axis.

For eg:

Y axis label which I got is 1,2,3,4,5 and so on. Now How to assign for corresponding label as,

If it's 2, then low.
If it's 10, then high.
If it's 15, then very high.
and then above all are supreme.

So my question is how to get Y axis label and then change and assign it? 
Is it possible to use strings in y axis?

[image]

For eg:

Instead of 2 in left and right y axis, I need to display as Low on Y axis. and also how to remove number in displayed graph? ie 2.00

Here is piece of code.

```
  List<BarEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    mDetectiveGraphExecutor = new DetectiveGraphExecutor(this);
    barChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
    YAxis leftAxis = barChart.getAxisRight();
    leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines();
    barChart.setDescription("");
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
    ViewPortHandler handlers = barChart.getViewPortHandler();
    handlers.setMaximumScaleX(10);
entries.add(new BarEntry(activities.size(), ++columnIndex)); //list of datas displaying.. 
        labels.add("Time");
        BarDataSet dataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# Counts");
        BarData data = new BarData(labels, dataset);
        barChart.setData(data);
```

Comment: Is it that you want to change the Y-axis labels from numbers to Strings or that you want to combine numbers and Strings in the y-axis?

Comment: i want to change that number to string. Why i am asking is for eg: if it's y axis points to 5, i need to show as low in left and right y axis label. So how to display that "low" in y axis.

Answer (score 1):

try to override the Y Axis renderer.
Here's an example:

```
setRendererRightYAxis(new YAxisRenderer(mViewPortHandler, mAxisRight, mRightAxisTransformer)
    {
        @Override
        protected void drawYLabels(Canvas c, float fixedPosition, float[] positions, float offset)
        {
            ArrayList<String> yLabels = new ArrayList<>();
            yLabels.add("10 " + getResources().getString(R.string.low));
            yLabels.add("20 " + getResources().getString(R.string.medium));
            yLabels.add("30 " + getResources().getString(R.string.high));

            for (int i = 0; i < _yLabels.size(); i++)
            {
                c.drawText(yLabels.get(i), fixedPosition, positions[i * 2 + 1] + offset, mAxisLabelPaint);
            }
        }
    });
```

another option is just to override the value formatter so for your example-

```
getAxisRight().setValueFormatter(new YAxisValueFormatter()
    {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, YAxis yAxis)
        {
            if(value == 0)
            {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.low));
            }
            else if(value == 1)
            {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.medium));
            }
            else
            {
                return getResources().getString(R.string.high));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need change the value in y axis then use this code

```
YAxis yAxis = water_graph.getAxisLeft();//for left side value changes

YAxis yAxis = water_graph.getAxisRight(); //for right side value changes

     yAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
     yAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                String str="";
                if(value<5)
                    str="Low";
                else if(value<10)
                    str="Medium";
                else if(value==10)
                    str="high";
                else
                    str="very high";
                return str;
            }
        });
```